# my Realme device is not connect as adb devices on mac but connecting on windows fluently

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, platform-tools

device is connecting perfectly on windows but not on mac devices is not asking permission to trust this device and showing offline while running adb devices command my phone is realme 9 pro speed addition,
i have tried on multiple macbook but still not connecting , also tried on diffrent windows laptops connected succesfully on each windows device. tried changing the cable , resarting server, downloaded latest platform-tools..

Comment: What MacOS is installed? Are those Macs Intel or M1 Macs?

Comment: mac11.5.2 intel chip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar issue on Realme Master GT and in my case solution was connecting wirelessly by adb. This feature was announced in android 11.

- Developer options > Wireless debugging > Pair device with pairing code
- Take ip, port, pairing code from phone - example: `ip:port = 192.168.150.120:37181` `pairing_code = 188231`
- Your phone and computer have to be connected to the same wifi network
- On mac: `adb pair [ip:port] [pairing_code]` - example: `adb pair 192.168.150.120:37181 188231`
- On mac: `adb connect 192.168.150.120:37181`
- On mac: `adb devices`

After last command your device should be properly listed and ready to run `npm react-native run-android` :)

Comment: did you find a way to fix the usb issue?

Comment: no i just use wireless method not going to but any realme device again.

Comment: @RausonAli i had the same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315007/adb-could-not-connect-to-device-on-macos-but-on-windows/75358221#75358221) and on my case, there was a bug in the current ui

Comment: thanks a ton for this. i wasn't able to connect my realme gt via usb to macbook no matter what. this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Select "transfer photos" from usb options after connecting data cable. It will be connected on ADB.