# adb could not connect to device on macos but on windows

Tags: android, windows, macos, adb

I want to connect my mobilephone (xiaomi lite 11) for android development (usb debugging) with my mac.

On my windows machine, it connects automaticly and everything is fine. But if i want to connect the same mobilephone with the mac it does not work.

On the mac:
I see the dialog with the connect options (file transfer, mtp...) its open, and close after a second, and open again and close after 1 second, and so one.

`adb devices` gives this to me:

```
% adb devices
List of devices attached
51ef87ce    offline
% adb devices
List of devices attached
% adb devices
List of devices attached
51ef87ce    offline
% adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I got another mobilephone, and this connects fine with the mac.

So the problem exist between my xiaomi and the mac and over usb! I can connect the mobilephone via wifi and its working fine.

I found a related question, but the only answer is to use the wifi ([my Realme device is not connect as adb devices on mac but connecting on windows fluently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72357792/my-realme-device-is-not-connect-as-adb-devices-on-mac-but-connecting-on-windows))

I've update the adb and android studio to the latest stable.

Has someone this issue in the past and got its phone working via usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is located in the MiUI 12.5.6. It also blocks sometimes Updates to newer Versions.

So i fix this with:

- change region to andorra
- try manual update
- update to 12.5.7
- change region to my real region

Now the connection work, and i can debug and install apps over usb.